SQL Query that Loops Table1 Based on Unique ID - Returns Values Missing from Table2
Edited this question to add more details:
Table examples used:
table 1: names



ID
names




1
sue


2
john



table 2: training



ID
type




1
winetasting


2
beerdrinking


3
whiskeyshots


4
shooters



table 3: log
Note: result is just yes = 1 or no = 0 (complete/not completed)



ID
nameid
typeid
result




1
1
1
1


2
1
2
0


3
2
3
1



Question: I want to return all students with training they have NOT YET COMPLETED. So, for instance, I am looking at the log table, and want to extract nameid, and then all typeids NOT taken yet.  So, it's comparing typeid field of log table to table 2 of list of training types - and returning training NOT COMPLETED.



ID
nameid
typeid




1
1
2


2
1
3


3
1
4


4
2
1


5
2
2


4
2
4



OR THE text results



ID
nameid
typeid




1
sue
beerdrinking


2
sue
whiskeyshots


3
sue
shooters


4
john
winetasting


5
john
beertasking


6
john
shooters



So, results would show that Sue needs to complete training 2, 3 and 4.  And John would have to complete 1, 2 and 4.
It's almost like a NOT EXISTS or NOT IN. I have tried most joins.  I am almost thinking this is a FOR EACH nameid, loop through table 3 and find all records from  table 2 not in table 3 based on nameid and typeid, and build a temporary table.  Maybe union?
Any resource links you can point out that might be similar to this, please let me know, or suggestions.
Thank you.

Do you have a separate table that has a unique list of all possible student_id? Also what happens if the row doesn't exist at all in table 1? Can you show an actual example with some sample rows?

I added more details to the question :) thank you.

Why do you have sue  shooters but not john  shooters in the expected results?

made a mistake when typing - updated results

Looks like a simple cross-join of the two main tables, with a NOT EXISTS anti-join against the log table.
SELECT
  n.ID,
  n.names,
  t.type
FROM names n
CROSS JOIN training t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM log l
    WHERE l.nameid = n.id
      AND l.typeid = t.id
      AND l.result = 1
);

db<>fiddle

Worked like a charm thank you - I was going wrong with the where not exists .... select 1 from log 1 area.
